# Routeprovider in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm really new to Angular and I was trying to add a routeProvider to my app but it keep giving me this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

This is what my index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'components/splash.html',
        controller: 'segmentListCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

myApp.controller('segmentListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data/segments.json').success(function (data){
        $scope.segmentList = data;
    });
}]);
```

This is the content of the splash.html that i'm using as template for my routing:

```
<div id="splash" class="row" ng-controller="segmentListCtrl">
    <div class="columns segment" ng-repeat="segment in segmentList">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>{{segment.title}}</h2>
            <h5>{{segment.sub}}</h5>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before I tried to add the ng-route everything wos working fine. But since I've tried to split it up I keep getting the error and I don't know how to fix it.
Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You don't have to declare the controller twice. Remove ng-controller="segmentListCtrl" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It apears to me that you have a syntax error in your `app config` declaration:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'components/splash.html',
        controller: 'segmentListCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Should be:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'components/splash.html',
        controller: 'segmentListCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

AS you can see, the final ']' is missing.
Tell me if this solved for you. Thanks

Comment: Hello,  user20. If thats the answer, please accept it. Sorry to bother. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your `myApp.config` you forgot the closing brace `]` at the end.

Also since you're new to angular in your `.when('/' ....)` when you specify the controller it's equivalent to putting an `ng-controller` at the top of your template so there's no need to do it again in the template itself.

So this:

```
<div id="splash" class="row" ng-controller="segmentListCtrl">
```

would be fine as

```
<div id="splash" class="row">
```